# "Object not found" error within a user defined function, eval() function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function for a task I need to do many times (running a cox proportional hazards function over multiple imputed datasets).  When I pass the necessary objects to my user-defined function, however, it gives an error, stating that the object cannot be found. I think this is because the object is defined within a dataframe that is specified with the "data=" argument within the cch() function. Can anyone help me with this?

Example data:

```
my.list<-list(my.df1 <- data.frame(my.id = 1:100, my.time = rlnorm(100), 
my.event= c(rbinom(50,1,0.2),rep(1,50)), my.det=rbinom(100,1,0.5), 
sub= c(rep(1,50), rbinom(50, 1, 0.1))),  my.df2 <- data.frame(my.id = 1:100, 
my.time = rlnorm(100), my.event= c(rbinom(50,1,0.2),rep(1,50)), 
my.det=rbinom(100,1,0.5), sub= c(rep(1,50), rbinom(50, 1, 0.1))))
```

Outside my user-defined function, this works:

```
library(KMsurv)
library(survival)
cch(Surv(my.time,my.event)~as.factor(my.det), data=my.df1, subcoh=~sub, 
id=~my.id, cohort.size=500)
```

However, this does not work (this is an example function, not the real function as the real function is more complex and runs analyses on multiple datasets, then combines them):

```
myfun<-function(dflist,time,event){
for (i in 1:length(dflist)){
out<-cch(Surv(time,event)~as.factor(my.det), data=dflist[[i]], 
subcoh=~sub, id=~my.id, cohort.size=500)
print(out)}
}   
myfun(my.list,my.time,my.event)
```

I get this error: "Error in Surv(time, event) : object 'my.time' not found".

I found some posts about using an eval(substitute()) function to deal with a similar problem, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you planning on doing it on more variables, thus it is important to be able to input time/event? or do you just want to do it for multiple data.frames?

Comment: You sure you got that right? First thing: you should pass `my.det` to your function to avoid depending on it being in the parent environment.  Second,  I bet you've got your `my.list` with one too many sub-levels of lists, so the `dflist[[i]]` isn't pointing to what you think it is.

Comment: @ James Tobin, yes, I need to be able to put in different time/event variables. Also, I'd like to be able to put in different determinants/explanatory variables, but for the sake of simplicity I didn't mention that. Gives the same error, though.

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft: On your first comment: I don't understand it, could you explain please? I would like to pass my.det to the function too (to be able to vary that, too), but for the sake of simplicity I left it out now. You think that causes a problem?

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft: on your second comment: I dont have any sublists. The only objects listed are data frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You need to keep in mind that R doesn't know what's `my.time` and `my.event`. You have to parse them with quotes and then unqoute them in order to parse it into `Surv`

```
myfun<-function(dflist,time,event){
  for (i in 1:length(dflist)){
    time <- noquote(time)
    event <- noquote(event)
    out<-cch(Surv(dflist[[i]][, time], dflist[[i]][, event])~as.factor(my.det), data=dflist[[i]], 
             subcoh=~sub, id=~my.id, cohort.size=500)
    print(out)}
}   
myfun(my.list,"my.time","my.event")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your solution works, but doesn't really solve my problem, as I need to be able to put in different "time variables" and "event variables". Preferably, I'd also be flexible in "my.det", the determinant(s). Any more suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer, it will work now for every variables you parse, check above

Comment: Wow it worked, thanks so much!! I"ll look into this parsing thing for future purposes :)