# how to evaluate character as variable name

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

I am having difficulty understanding how to get R to treat a character as the name of a variable from a data frame.

I'm attempting to do something like the following

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)

df <- data_frame(time = rexp(30),
                 cens = sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE),
                 var = rnorm(30))

var_int <- 'var'

survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ var_int, data = df)
```

I am aware that something like this would work

```
survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ df[[var_int]], data = df)
```

but more generally I'm trying to understand how I can get R to treat `'var'` as the variable `var` coming from `df` rather than the character itself.

I had thought this may work, but it does not, and I don't quite understand how to apply `eval()` appropriately in this case.

```
survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ eval(var_int), data = df)
```

Comment: did you try `get()`?

Comment: Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772703/problems-with-calling-variables-in-r-survival-package) which is more or less a duplicate.