# What is the mistake in this R function

Tags: r

```
customFunc<-function(variable,compare,data) {
     a.data <- tally(shuffle(variable)~compare,data=data,format="percent")
     return(a.data)
}
```

I get this error message where survival and gender are two data in my data slasher

```
customFunc(survival,gender,data=slasher)
 Error in sample(x, replace = replace, prob = prob, groups = groups) : 
  object 'survival' not found
```

But just this works

```
tally(shuffle(survival)~gender,data=slasher,format="percent")
```

Comment: This answer might have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617354/object-not-found-error-within-a-user-defined-function-eval-function

Comment: What package does that `shuffle` function belong to?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Mosaic